# django-allauth google callback url not working on production

Tags: django, django-allauth, google-developers-console

I have integrated google login using [django allauth](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html).

For my local it works fine.

But for production url it is not working.

For production it redirect to

```
localhost:8054/accounts/google/login/callback/?state=U0Y1kkth3jNB&code=4%2FbQFuzMf9I-RTXYJUJ-IhUyx36O-gAV00qFvtQHl3nNHzP_QVDJCfe-5f4a1zR12t_P8PgizD-cc95Hhk497fRyY&scope=profile+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.profile
```

expected :

```
mysite.com/accounts/google/login/callback/?state=U0Y1kkth3jNB&code=4%2FbQFuzMf9I-RTXYJUJ-IhUyx36O-gAV00qFvtQHl3nNHzP_QVDJCfe-5f4a1zR12t_P8PgizD-cc95Hhk497fRyY&scope=profile+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.profile
```

**local (working):**

```
in google api 

Authorised redirect URIs = 127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/google/login/callback/
```

**production :**

```
Authorised redirect URIs = mysite.com/accounts/google/login/callback/
```

Comment: What is the result of **`print(Site.objects.get(id=settings.SITE_ID).__dict__)`** ? `from django.conf import settings` and 
`from django.contrib.sites.models import Site`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by [X-Forwarded-Host](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#std:setting-USE_X_FORWARDED_HOST)

in settings.py

```
USE_X_FORWARDED_HOST = True
```